# How to add images dynamically to android 3d carousel?

Tags: android, 3d, carousel

Im developing an app where I have used Android 3d carousel. But I want images to be loaded from my webservice, So anyone has clue how to do it?
Here is the url from where I m using this plugin:
[Android 3d carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, In that project there is class named circularMenu, in here, there is an array named pics, which is harcoded for the sample explanation.

What you can do is refer your images in that array through your webservice. Or rather convert your image files(obtained from webservice) to bitmap and then refer it directly to ImageView object present in same class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please give a code example? or if you can give me an example of image gallery, where I can swipe it infinite with center image to be bigger than other images

Comment: @VickyGonsalves need your help